# Rails 4 includes unscoping default scope of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have this setting:

In model Book:

```
default_scope -> { where(published: true) }
```

In model Author:

```
default_scope -> { where(english: true) }
scope :english_author_book, -> (book_ids) {includes(:book).where({ books: { id: book_ids } })}
```

I tried all kinds of stuff but I just can't remove the default scope of `Book`: `'positions'.'published' = 1` is always in the query

Is there a way to fix this? Thank you!

The association:

In model Book:

`has_many :authors, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :book`

Im model Author:

`belongs_to :book, :inverse_of => :authors`

Sorry about that the example seems unrealistic, but I can't post the full code here :/

Comment: can you paste the entire Book & Author model. Need to see the associations.

Comment: Hmm... this is weird. shouldn't a book belong to an author and author has_many books? Even though the other way around too does makes sense in some contexts when there could be more than one authors for a book. but then again wouldn't it be a has_and_belongs_to_many relation between the two models?

Comment: The example is made up just for this question. I should have made it more realistic :) In the real code, there is no has and belongs to many relation between the two models.

Comment: yes, that's right, you should have made the question more clear. Giving a close to something example of your issue, most of the times doesn't help us help you.

Comment: Yeah.. But I am not authorized to post the real code :/ 
Thank you for your help though!

Comment: That's fine. from this i can only tell you one thing. you should never use default_scope. it seldom helps and causes issues most of the times.

Comment: Right.. The code base I'm having is just messy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unscoped` to remove the default scope. Documentation available [here.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-unscope)

```
Book.unscoped.english_author_book(ids)
```

However, I highly highly highly cannot stress enough highly recommend you  **do not use a default scope.** They are incredibly inflexible as you have already found, tough to deal with, and almost always a bad idea.

Turn the default scope into a normal scope so you can do `Book.published` and your code will be much better for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the `english_author_book` is a scope of model `Author`. I can't find place to put `unscoped` in side the `includes`